# Why would scaling up increase latency?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

We are scaling the number of users on our GAE java app. We now have about triple the active users we had a few days ago.

We've noticed that average latency as reported by the GAE dashboard has increased almost by a factor of 2. There have been no code changes.

What would cause latency per request to go up just by having more users? Presumably in a well designed app, appengine would scale the number of instances so that our latency is kept to a minimum. I have not altered any of the default pending latency settings and similar.

**What are the most common design flaws in implementing an appengine app that would cause latency to go up as usage goes up?**

Contention on the datastore? The data we store is in seperate entity groups per user so this seems like a low probability.....

Comment: Instead of making us guess, why don't you tell us something about how your app works? Have you used AppStats to see where the time is being spent?

Comment: @NickJohnson totally unrelated to the question, but, welcome back :)

Comment: Realized I should add more information to this question. I'll close it for now and open a new question with more specifics.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more info about your app, for example writes to the datastore. If many clients write to the datastore, you will create a traffic jam if you use a single entity.

What you need to do is to measure each part how long it takes and compare the results between the two loads.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an issue with latency when setting "threadsafe" to "yes". Are you perhaps hitting the same [issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6323) as found here: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6323

**Update:**
By default, each web server processes only one request at a time. If you mark your application as thread-safe, App Engine may dispatch multiple requests to each web server in parallel. To do so, simply add a true element to appengine-web.xml as described in Using Concurrent Requests.

Comment: That bug report has to do with Python - I'm using Java. Also it seems to be fixed.

Comment: Have you tried setting <threadsafe>true</threadsafe> in the web.xml file? Perhaps this post is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292376/creating-multiples-instances-in-google-app-engine-java

Comment: @aloo: By default, each web server processes only one request at a time. If you mark your application as thread-safe, App Engine may dispatch multiple requests to each web server in parallel. To do so, simply add a <threadsafe>true</threadsafe> element to appengine-web.xml as described in Using Concurrent Requests.